Python ibm_db says no method called cursor exists for conn
IBM Documentation sample code says that after creating a connection as below with Python and ibm_db I should be able to get a cursor with "cursor = ibm_db.cursor(conn)" but all that happens is the error shown below after the code lines.
IBM docs say I need to update my ibm_db version to fix the error. I am at 3.2.3 now and if I run "PIP install --upgrade ibm_db" the response is that I already have the requested upgrade.
The code lines are: (I'm on Python 3.12.2) and interacting with Z/os 16.9.0
conn = ibm_db.connect(conn_string, "", "")
cursor = ibm_db.cursor(conn)

The error is:
cursor = ibm_db.cursor(conn)
AttributeError: module 'ibm_db' has no attribute 'cursor'

Is "cursor" supposed to be available under ibm_db  3.2.3  ???

Usually, you would say cursor = conn.cursor().

As Tim Roberts commented- the api is cursor = conn.cursor()
I don't see the syntax you are trying even in older releases or in the IBM documentation, so not sure where you got it from.
This is the definition of the cursor method-
https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/blob/master/ibm_db_dbi.py#L894

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\liddvdp\pylib\stored3.py", line 30, in 
cursor = conn.cursor()
AttributeError: 'ibm_db.IBM_DBConnection' object has no attribute 'cursor'

The code segment looks like:                                                                                                                                                                                       conn = ibm_db.connect(conn_string, "", "")
if conn:
print ("Successful Connection")
cursor = conn.cursor()
I get the 'Successful Connection'  msg display then the error comes on the
cursor = conn.cursor()

Seems as though it looks like the suggested format ?

The readme suggests you connect with ibm_db_dbi to use cursor https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/tree/master -
